# Error fecha en inglés después del setlocale()

Tags: php

Buenas devs mmm tengo un problema y es que al querer convertir mi fecha al idioma español usando estos métodos de php la fecha me sigue saliendo en inglés

**Supuesta forma de cambiar la fecha en español PHP**

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES');
echo strftime('%A %d de %B del %Y');
```

Lo que me imprime es lo siguiente

```
Monday 20 de April del 2020
```

Ayuda por favor

Comment: creo que hace falta informacion o debes tener un error en otra linea porque esta bien si quieres pruebalo aqui y veras que funciona [phptester](http://phptester.net)

Comment: Es que la informacion la traigo desde la base de datos pueda ser por eso porque segun veo en la pagina que pusiste si sale pero directo de php pero si traigo de la base de datos creo es el problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De alguna forma funciono para mi país (Ecuador) de esta manera

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es-EC');
```

Los codigos de paises los saque de esta página

[codigos de paises MICROSOFT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-lcid/a9eac961-e77d-41a6-90a5-ce1a8b0cdb9c?redirectedfrom=MSDN)